# Do ternary expressions within while statements get evaluated every loop

Tags: c#

I have a simple loop to calculate the hcf of two numbers to cancel down a fraction.

I'm wondering if the ternary expression within the while condition is recalculated on every loop and as such should be calculate once before and stored as a variable for performance purposes?

```
 public Fraction LowestForm()
        {
            int hcf = 1;
            int counter =2;
            while (counter <= (Numerator < Denominator ? Numerator : Denominator))
            {
                if (Numerator % counter == 0 && Denominator % counter == 0)
                {
                    hcf = counter;
                }  
                counter++;
            }
            return new Fraction(Numerator / hcf, Denominator / hcf);
        }
```

To clarify: I'm mainly concerned with the Rosylyn Compiler

Comment: even if compiler doesn't optimize that jitter will do (I think)

Comment: Is there only one compiler for C#? If not, then wouldn't the answer to this question depend on which compiler is being used? Might not hurt to mention it just in case.

Comment: @Rainbolt The behavior is defined in the language specs, and any compiler of the language would be obligated to honor it in order for it to be considered a C# compiler.

Comment: @Servy The behavior, in this case, is exactly the same whether the expression is resolved once outside of the loop or many times inside of the loop.

Comment: @Rainbolt Only if you can prove that those expressions always resolve to the same value.  Unless those are `const` expressions, the compiler wouldn't be able to prove that either way.  (If they are compile time constants than it would perform the operation once *at compile time*, and not run it at all at runtime, not even once outside of the loop.)

Comment: @Servy If the compiler can detect that `Numerator` and `Denominator` are never assigned outside of the constructor, then can't it prove that the expression never changes?

Comment: @Rainbolt Unless they're constants, it will basically never be able to prove such a thing.  The naming convention suggests that they're properties, not fields, so we have no idea what those property getters are even doing.  They could be using a random number generator to return different values on each invocation for all it knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this depends. If any expression (or any subexpression, the particular type of subexpression is not important and the location of subexpression, i.e. in the condition of the loop or inside the body of the loop is not important either) does not depend on variables that are modified in the loop, can be moved out of the loop and calculated just once, the optimizer will do this. C# has pretty good optimizer.

In debug build nothing will be optimized. Every expression will be recalculated.

As a first priority I would recommend increasing clarity and readability of your code. Other than that try to minimize the time to develop working code. You need to help optimizer only in critical pieces of code or when you see that for some reason optimizer is not doing a good job. Rarely, but sometimes this happens.

Comment: Is it good practice to do this yourself rather than rely on the optimizer though? 

Also, I've added the counter incrementer! Good spot!

Comment: @JamesHughes rely on the optimizer? what benefit you get from having all of this in one line? its more readable if you define local variable. don't worry about extra variable you are defining. it doesn't hurt any body

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary You could define the variable inside of the loop, so that doesn't address James Hughes' comment question. In my opinion, declaring the variable outside of the loop makes it more obvious that the value is only calculated once, which makes the code more readable.

Comment: If `Numerator` and `Denominator` are compile time constants, then yes, the compiler could perform the operation at compile time, but if they're not (and they look like properties based on the naming convention), and they're actual variables, it couldn't do any optimizations here.

Comment: @Servy, in this case MSIL generator and JIT are part of compiler. Depending on the definition they will act differently. JIT can move subexpressions out of the loop.

Comment: @KirillKobelev The runtime is not in fact a part of the compiler.  It's the runtime; it's a separate thing.

Comment: JIT is part of compiler. Unfortunately for you, but this is so.

Comment: It's *a* compiler, in the sense that it is compiling one language into another.  It's not a C# compiler, as it's not compiling C# code.  The MS C# compiler compiles C# code into MSIL code, the runtime, which is an entirely separate entity from that C# compiler, compiles that code into machine code when the program runs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, how else would the while statement know when to complete?  It needs to re-evaluate the expression in its entirety on each iteration in order to know when it can exit the loop.

That being said, when the CIL is created, it most likely optimizes it out of the loop.

Comment: Technically the answer is **WRONG**. The OP is explicitly about ternary expression part and not about the whole expression.

Comment: @KirillKobelev so by that logic, if I hire you to repaint my garage but you repaint the whole house and then, when I ask you if the garage has been repainted, it would be incorrect for you to say "yes"?

Comment: Your logic does not work. The title of the OP has not changed. And it asks directly about subexpression.